# Почему выводится каракуля?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    Stack OPZ(20);

    string str;
    int point = 0, k = 0;
    int arr[20];

    cin >> str;
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (str[j] != '+' || str[j] != '-' || str[j] != '*' || str[j] != '/') {
            arr[k++] = str[j];
        }
        cout << (char) arr[k];

    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эх, снова расплывчатый вопрос... Какой именно ввод вы делаете? Какой текст? Все данные "в студию"!

Comment: @vladimir_ki Ввод: 1+2 Вывод: Каракуля какая-то. Вроде должен добавить 1 и 2 в массив и вывести 12. Нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему выводится каракуля?

Потому что стоит `k++`, после которого стоит вывод `arr[k]`
т.е. выводится всегда то, что было в `arr` до его заполнения, то бишь мусор.

Comment: т.е сделать cout << (char)arr[k++]; ??? Опять то же выводит. Каракуля

Comment: а именно *каракуля* получается из-за того, что массив не был инициализирован.

Comment: нет, сделать:

    if ( ... ) {
      arr[k] = str[j];
      cout << (char) arr[k];
      ++k;
    }
или

    if ( ... ) {
      cout << (char)( arr[k++] = str[j] );
    }

Comment: @mega Сделал так: 
if(str[j] != '+' || str[j] != '-' || str[j] != '*' || str[j] != '/') 
 cout << (char)(arr[k++] = str[j]);
но выводит он 1+2. Он же + не должен вывести =/

Comment: все || надо заменить на &&

Comment: упс. Запутался. Спасибо!